# Domain controller not allowing me to connect to it over IPSec tunnel

Tags: windows, active-directory, ipsec

I'm trying to connect a Windows 7 computer to a domain controller over an IPSec tunnel. The tunnel has formed and the network is accessible. I have set the IPSec connection to use the windows domain controller as its DNS server and I have done an nslookup to ensure that it was in fact doing so. What is strange is that if I use Windows explorer and type in it's IP it will allow me to log into it and view the shares, but when I click on the file share on the Windows 7 machine to tell it to connect to the remote AD server I can tell from sniffing packets that the request is in fact reaching the server and the connection is being rejected. Does anyone know what needs to occur before the domain controller will allow connections to it from the remote computers through an IPSec tunnel?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Windows firewall settings?

Comment: I wish I knew. I suspect there might be a setting allowing it to propagate over the tunnel, but honestly I'm not a Windows engineer and don't even have much of an idea of where to look.